# Iterating through database depends on attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, loops

I need to iterate through a database table where it's conditions will change:

```
<%# if @story.category == 5 %>

<% @users.where(generalLabour: 1).find_each do |user| %>

<% else %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>

.... Iterate and display data.....
```

So I need to do something like this, unfortunately this does not seem to work as I cannot run statements like this alongside else statements

I also need to do integer comparisons:

```
<% @users.where(starttime: > 12 ).find_each do |user| %>
```

How I do something like this?

Maybe I should do all this in Javascript instead of rails?

Comment: Do something like what? What do you have and what is the desired outcome?

Comment: @users.where(starttime: > 12 ).find_each integer comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
query= ""
if @story.category == 5
   query = "generalLabour = 1"
elsif @story.category == 4
   query = "generalLabour = 2"
elsif @story.category == 6
   query = "generalLabour = 3"
end

@users.where(query).each do |user|
   .........
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed, oh and how do I do integer comparisons? Like <% @users.where(starttime: > 12 ).find_each do |user| %>

Comment: and can you add two varables to the where? like @user.where(query, query2)?

Comment: And I need to add two variables per query:       query2 = "SaturdayS <= story.startTime, SaturdayE >= story.endTime,"

Comment: yes you can add these variable to the where condition

Comment: Yuck. You can do the same by just creating a hash with the mappings `{ 5 => 1, 4 => 2, 6 => 3 }[@story.category]`

Answer (score 1):

```
query= ""
if @story.category == 5
  query = "SaturdayS <= #{story.startTime}"
elsif @story.category == 4
  query = "SaturdayE >= #{story.endTime}"
end

@users.where(query).each do |user|
 .........
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash with mappings:

```
x = { 5 => 1, 4 => 2, 6 => 3 }[@story.category]
```

Or use [case statement](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) (which is the ruby version of `switch`):

```
x = case(@story.category)
when 5
  3
when 4
  2 
when 6
  3
else
  raise "Doh! I did not think of this."
end
```

But it is very likely that you are just doing it wrong. Hardcoding IDs in your application is not a good solution and you should instead solve this by setting up a proper association and getting the related items through it.